# Xcode quit unexpectedly for my project (not in Xcode 4.6.3)

Tags: xcode

Since this morning I'm not able to open my Project in Xcode 5.

The message received is the following:

> Process:         Xcode [934] Path:
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode Identifier:
> com.apple.dt.Xcode Version:         5.0 (3332.22) Build Info:
> IDEApplication-3332022000000000~2 Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
> Parent Process:  launchd [123] User ID:         501
>
> Date/Time:       2013-09-12 09:58:32.024 +0200 OS Version:      Mac OS
> X 10.8.4 (12E3067) Report Version:  10
>
> Interval Since Last Report:          4855 sec Crashes Since Last
> Report:           15 Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  506 sec
> Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   15 Anonymous UUID:
> F219D8B3-C23D-E7C1-CAC3-FA51A899F6F1
>
> **Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: IDEContainer - uniquing lock**
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
> 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
>
> Application Specific Information: ProductBuildVersion: 5A1412 [934]
> stack overflow
>
> Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: IDEContainer - uniquing lock 0
> libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff85c94212 __pthread_kill + 10
> 1   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x00007fff907e8704 pthread_kill +
> 90 2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x00007fff9082cc11 __abort + 159
> 3   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x00007fff9082db77 __stack_chk_fail
>
> - 195 4   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010196bf7a DVTMacroExpressionByParsingStringAsList + 3943 5
>   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore      0x00000001075f4e6d
>   xc_get_parsedValueForMacroName + 380
>
> Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager 0
> libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x00007fff85c94d16 kevent + 10 1
> libdispatch.dylib                 0x00007fff8d1a9dea _dispatch_mgr_invoke
>
> - 883 2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8d1a99ee _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54
>
> Thread 2:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib
> 0x00007fff85c92686 mach_msg_trap + 10 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib
> 0x00007fff85c91c42 mach_msg + 70 2   com.apple.CoreFoundation
> 0x00007fff88ed5233 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 195 3
> com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff88eda916 __CFRunLoopRun +
> 1078 4   com.apple.CoreFoundation         0x00007fff88eda0e2
> CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290 5   com.apple.Foundation
> 0x00007fff86c5a546 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] +
> 356 6   com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fff86cb8562
> **NSThread__main** + 1345 7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff907e7352 _pthread_start + 327 8   libsystem_c.dylib
> 0x00007fff907d3d81 thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 3: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff85c92686
> mach_msg_trap + 10 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib
> 0x00007fff85c91c42 mach_msg + 70 2   com.apple.CoreFoundation
> 0x00007fff88ed5233 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 195 3
> com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff88eda916 __CFRunLoopRun +
> 1078 4   com.apple.CoreFoundation         0x00007fff88eda0e2
> CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290 5   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase
> 0x000000010b06975a -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener
> listenerThreadImplementation] + 164 6   com.apple.Foundation
> 0x00007fff86cb8562 **NSThread__main** + 1345 7   libsystem_c.dylib
> 0x00007fff907e7352 _pthread_start + 327 8   libsystem_c.dylib
> 0x00007fff907d3d81 thread_start + 13
>
> Thread 4:: com.apple.CFSocket.private 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib
> 0x00007fff85c94322 __select + 10 1   com.apple.CoreFoundation
> 0x00007fff88f19f46 __CFSocketManager + 1302 2   libsystem_c.dylib
> 0x00007fff907e7352 _pthread_start + 327 3   libsystem_c.dylib
> 0x00007fff907d3d81 thread_start + 13

I have no Plug-ins and I've tried to remove the files in .xcodeproj except for project.pbxproj without any result.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you are using Xcode 5 developer preview. There seems some issue with Xcode 5. Even I faced difficulty in debugging my project.

Comment: Right, the strage thing is that it worked well for 2 days and now...

Comment: For me, it worked for many weeks. Please post this issue to Apple Developers forum.

Comment: Posted on Developer forum...

Comment: Here the link:https://devforums.apple.com/thread/204401?tstart=0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SOLVED!!

I Found that in project.xcodeproj --> project.pbxproj, there were many backslashes in the LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS variable.

Removing those backslashes solved my issue!

Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0):

Replace below files files from your project file(if you have backup of your project):

1. pods
2. projectname.xcworkspace
3. podfile.lock, podfile
4. add pods in podfile if any pod missing and install pods
5. Build your project and run

Please get project backup in zip this will help to solve this error.